# Замена url в строке на рабочие c помощью PHP

Tags: url, php, html

```
preg_match_all("~(http://[^ ]+)~", $msg, $urls);
//ищу подстроки url
for ($i=0; $i< count($urls[0]); $i++) {
    $msg= str_replace($urls[$i], '<a href="'.$urls[$i].'">'.$urls[$i].'</a>' , $msg);
}
//пытаюсь заменить их на рабочие с помощью <a>
```

Но выводит на страницу "Array" в виде ссылки. Что исправить? Может есть какая-то альтернатива?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$msg= str_replace($urls[0][$i], '<a href="'.$urls[0][$i].'">'.$urls[0][$i].'</a>' , $msg);
```

Но вообще регулярка у вас кривая) [Рекомендую ресурс](http://regexlib.ru/uri/)

Comment: А вы можете сказать откуда берутся эти вторые скобки? Массив двумерный?

Comment: Ну, да) Вы же сами проверяете `count($urls[0])`, т.е. узнаете длину массива `$urls[0]`. Ну и просто preg_match_all возвращает двумерный массив вида `array[номер_подстроки_в_регулярке][номер_вхождения]`.